# using fragments in android for displaying views

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to use Fragments In Android

- This involves using fragments
- Dynamic way of using it
- This has two activities

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.simpledynamicfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Fragment frag=new Fragment();
        FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();       
        FragmentTransaction transaction=FM.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.layout.fragment,frag,"fragment1");
        transaction.commit();


    }


}
```

**FragmentActivity.java**

```
package com.example.simpledynamicfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentActivity extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

**Log**::

```
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simpledynamicfragment/com.example.simpledynamicfragment.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030001 (com.example.simpledynamicfragment:layout/fragment) for fragment Fragment{45fc8ee0 #0 id=0x7f030001 fragment1}
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030001 (com.example.simpledynamicfragment:layout/fragment) for fragment Fragment{45fc8ee0 #0 id=0x7f030001 fragment1}
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
10-31 17:17:41.927: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  ... 11 more
```

- I have only run time errors

How to resolve this error?

### {EDIT}

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.simpledynamicfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        My_Fragment  frag=new My_Fragment();
        FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();       
        FragmentTransaction transaction=FM.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.layout.fragment_container,frag,"fragment1");
        transaction.commit();


    }


}
```

I have changed the class

**My_Fragment.java**

```
public class My_Fragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

**Log**::

```
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simpledynamicfragment/com.example.simpledynamicfragment.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030001 (com.example.simpledynamicfragment:layout/fragment) for fragment My_Fragment{45fc91a0 #0 id=0x7f030001 fragment1}
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030001 (com.example.simpledynamicfragment:layout/fragment) for fragment My_Fragment{45fc91a0 #0 id=0x7f030001 fragment1}
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
10-31 17:31:13.037: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  ... 11 more
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Yellow"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout" >



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Name "FragmentActivity" class something else, [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) is already an android lib class

Comment: also post your activity xml

Comment: you have not changed this  `transaction.add(R.layout.fragment,frag,"fragment1");` post your activity xml

Comment: @smriti3 pls change the add method quoting from docs **The first argument passed to add() is the ViewGroup in which the fragment should be placed, specified by resource ID**. your first argument must be resource id but you have a layout

Comment: @smriti3 your log says No view found for id 0x7f030001 (com.example.simpledynamicfragment:layout/fragment) for fragment My_Fragment{45fc91a0 #0 id=0x7f030001 fragment1}

Comment: @smriti3 post your activity xml pls

Comment: @smriti3 add   `<FrameLayout 
      android:id="@+id/fragment_container" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />` to your activity xml and use  `transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,frag,"fragment1");`

Comment: @smriti3  your framelayour is the container to which you add your framgent. it has an id `android:id="@+id/fragment_container` and that is what you use in `transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,frag,"fragment1")` i posted this bcoz you never posted your activity xml even if repeatedly asked for one

Comment: Yes finally works .... the tutorial i followed this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSRJynmOvFo is misleading .... have a check at this link ....  .....

Comment: @smriti3 following tutorials is fine but the problem is you need to understand whats happening and for that you need not refer anything except developer docs.

Comment: But .... In the video i clearly can see speaker has not added the fragment part in activity_main.xml ...... guess he skipped that part ! ..... using developer Docs is hard for newbies ... most of the stuff i am learning from stackoverflow using conversation with you & other developers .... you guys help me a lot ... thanks !

Comment: @smriti3 What does your `R.layout.fragment` layout contains ? Please post layout.

Comment: @ GrIsHu .... I had not included fragment part in relative layout ..... that was the mistake i was doing .... Raghunandan  i/p above clered that ... so i added the lines he pointed me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
  public class FragmentActivity extends Fragment{
```

To

```
  public class MyFragment extends Fragment{ // as pointed by Ed George
```

Ans this

```
  Fragment frag=new Fragment();
```

To

```
  MyFragment frag=new MyFragment();
```

Also change this

```
  transaction.add(R.layout.fragment,frag,"fragment1");
```

to

```
  transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,frag,"fragment1");
```

fragment_container is the container where you add your fragment the id may be different in your case